# Call onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) in a fragment

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, menu

I have a fragment that is called before then activity's `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` method.
First is called fragment's `onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)` method.
When this method is finished is called the other one activity's method.
The problem is that i need to work inside `onCreateView()` fragment method with the menu, so i'm finding a way to call first the menu activity's method.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_media_annuale, container, false);  

        final StudentGrades activity = ((StudentGrades)getActivity());
        //here the activity onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
        //method have to be called

        //here i begin to check something with the menu 
        //(for this reason i need that it's ready)
        //
        //...
        //
        return rootView;

}
```

i'm reading some solutions for example calling: `activity.invalidateOptionsMenu();` method. But it doesnt work.

Comment: What are you trying to do, exactly? Any changes a Fragment needs to make to the menu is usually done in the Fragment's `onCreateOptionsMenu()` method.

Comment: I tried to ovveride the onCreateOptionsMenu() of the fragment but still first is called the onCreateOptionsMenu() of the activity, i need to have the menu ready inside the onCreateView() because in this method i have to check something with the menu

Comment: Could that something be, instead, passed as an argument to the Fragment?

Comment: i don't understand what do you mean, can you give me an example?

Comment: Have a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17436298/how-to-pass-a-variable-from-activity-to-fragment-and-pass-it-back