# Android set Textview from another fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-studio, nullpointerexception

I want to setText to a Textview from a fragment to another fragment.

How would I do that? Right now I am getting a: *java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference*

**FragmentRonde1.java**

```
lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            ListClickedFragment newFragment = new ListClickedFragment();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);

            transaction.commit();

            Cursor c2 = db.getIdOfSelectedItem(id);

            ListClickedFragment fragmentRonde1 = new ListClickedFragment();

            if (c2 != null) {
                c2.moveToFirst();

                // i want to set listClickedTitle from here but listClickedTitle is in ListClickedFragment
                fragmentRonde1.gettext(c2.getString(c2.getColumnIndex("title")));

            }

        }
    });
```

Here is the class for the fragment where ListCLickedTitle is : **ListClickedFragment**

```
public class ListClickedFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

TextView tvTitle, tvDesc, tv, oop;


public ListClickedFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}




@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    final View rootview2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list_clicked, container, false);

    tvTitle = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listClickedTitle);

    return rootview2;
}

public void gettext (String text) {

    tvTitle.setText(text);

}
}
```

**LOGCAT**

```
    10-28 09:37:25.373 14349-14349/justin.drawer E/InputEventReceiver: Exception dispatching input event.
10-28 09:37:25.381 14349-14349/justin.drawer E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
10-28 09:37:25.420 14349-14349/justin.drawer E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
10-28 09:37:25.420 14349-14349/justin.drawer E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at justin.drawer.ListClickedFragment.gettext(ListClickedFragment.java:40)
10-28 09:37:25.420 14349-14349/justin.drawer E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at justin.drawer.FragmentRonde1$1.onItemClick(FragmentRonde1.java:71)
10-28 09:37:25.420 14349-14349/justin.drawer E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:310)
10-28 09:37:25.420 14349-14349/justin.drawer E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1145)
10-28 09:37:25.420 14349-14349/justin.drawer E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3042)
10-28 09:37:25.420 14349-14349/justin.drawer E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchUp(AbsListView.java:3891)
10-28 09:37:25.420 14349-14349/justin.drawer E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3656)
10-28 09:37:25.420 14349-14349/justin.drawer E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:9294)
10-28 09:37:25.420 14349-14349/justin.drawer E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2547)
10-28 09:37:25.420 14349-14349/justin.drawer E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2240)
10-28 09:37:25.420 14349-14349/justin.drawer E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
10-28 09:37:25.420 14349-14349/justin.drawer E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
10-28 09:37:25.420 14349-14349/justin.drawer E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
10-28 09:37:25.420 14349-14349/justin.drawer E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
10-28 09:37:25.420 14349-14349/justin.drawer E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
10-28 09:37:25.420 14349-14349/justin.drawer E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
10-28 09:37:25.420 14349-14349/justin.drawer E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
10-28 09:37:25.420 14349-14349/justin.drawer E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
10-28 09:37:25.420 14349-14349/justin.drawer E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
10-28 09:37:25.420 14349-14349/justin.drawer E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
10-28 09:37:25.420 14349-14349/justin.drawer E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
10-28 09:37:25.420 14349-14349/justin.drawer E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
10-28 09:37:25.420 14349-14349/justin.drawer E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
10-28 09:37:25.420 14349-14349/justin.drawer E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
10-28 09:37:25.420 14349-14349/justin.drawer E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
10-28 09:37:25.420 14349-14349/justin.drawer E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
10-28 09:37:25.420 14349-14349/justin.drawer E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
10-28 09:37:25.420 14349-14349/justin.drawer E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
10-28 09:37:25.420 14349-14349/justin.drawer E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2403)
10-28 09:37:25.420 14349-14349/justin.drawer E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1737)
10-28 09:37:25.420 14349-14349/justin.drawer E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2765)
10-28 09:37:25.420 14349-14349/justin.drawer E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:60)
10-28 09:37:25.420 14349-14349/justin.drawer E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:60)
10-28 09:37:25.420 14349-14349/justin.drawer E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2364)
10-28 09:37:25.420 14349-14349/justin.drawer E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:9514)
10-28 09:37:25.420 14349-14349/justin.drawer E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4230)
10-28 09:37:25.420 14349-14349/justin.drawer E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4096)
10-28 09:37:25.420 14349-14349/justin.drawer E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642)
10-28 09:37:25.420 14349-14349/justin.drawer E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3695)
10-28 09:37:25.420 14349-14349/justin.drawer E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3661)
10-28 09:37:25.420 14349-14349/justin.drawer E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3787)
10-28 09:37:25.420 14349-14349/justin.drawer E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3669)
10-28 09:37:25.420 14349-14349/justin.drawer E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3844)
10-28 09:37:25.420 14349-14349/justin.drawer E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642)
10-28 09:37:25.420 14349-14349/justin.drawer E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3695)
10-28 09:37:25.420 14349-14349/justin.drawer E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3661)
10-28 09:37:25.420 14349-14349/justin.drawer E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3669)
10-28 09:37:25.420 14349-14349/justin.drawer E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642)
10-28 09:37:25.420 14349-14349/justin.drawer E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5922)
10-28 09:37:25.420 14349-14349/justin.drawer E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5896)
10-28 09:37:25.420 14349-14349/justin.drawer E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5857)
10-28 09:37:25.420 14349-14349/justin.drawer E/MessageQueue-JNI:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceive
10-28 09:37:25.420 14349-14349/justin.drawer D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
```

Comment: obviously its gonna be null object, try creating a method in the fragment which hold the textview and call that method after taking fragment instance from another fragment.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17436298/how-to-pass-a-variable-from-activity-to-fragment-and-pass-it-back 
You can pass strings to the fragment with `setArguments(Bundle)` method.

Comment: So i made a Method of it but it still gives me a nullpointerEcxeption. Can you look into my updated question? @AndreiVerdes

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a null pointer exception because your views are inflated after onCreateView has been called. 
You should instead pass a Bundle or String parameter in the constructor for your ListClickedFrgament and then use that to set the text.

ListClickedFragment:

```
    String textToSet;
    public ListClickedFragment(String text) {
           this.textToSet = text;
    }
```

Set this text to your textview in OnViewCreated method of ListClickedFragment.

In fragmentRonde1:

```
    ListClickedFragment fragmentRonde1 = new ListClickedFragment(c2.getString(c2.getColumnIndex("title")));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: So where you put this.textToSet that's where I put my textview and settext to text? I don't fully understand yet but I see where you're going @hadi

Comment: No Justin, the point is textview is a UI component, you can only get its reference after onCreateView method has finished. What you will do is override onViewCreated method in your ListClickedFragment, in that method you can use the _textToSet_ string and set it to your textview.

Comment: I see what you mean! I will try it out and accept as answer if it works! @hadi

Comment: Been trying around but I am still getting a NullPointerException :( Also can't get it to work in a bundle. @hadi

Comment: 2 points.
1. replace this line :
tvTitle = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listClickedTitle);

Answer (score 1):

```
tvTitle = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listClickedTitle);
```

find tvTitle in your activity instead of fragment

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
I made some suppositions here, I don't really understand why you have 2 instances of the same fragment...and you don't have a transaction with the second(`fragmentRonde1`)...this won't show on the activity...I'm a bit confused but maybe this will help.

Edit: Why were you getting the NullPointerException the second time? Because you only called the constructor for `ListClickedFragment fragmentRonde1`. Not doing a transaction with it, not adding/replacing it in some `FrameLayout` won't trigger the `onCreateView()`
...the View won't be inflated, hence the TextView would be null.

```
lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        ListClickedFragment newFragment = ListClickedFragment.newInstance();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);

        transaction.commit();

        Cursor c2 = db.getIdOfSelectedItem(id);

        ListClickedFragment fragmentRonde1;

        if (c2 != null) {
            c2.moveToFirst();
            fragmentRonde1 = ListClickedFragment.newInstance(c2.getString(c2.getColumnIndex("title")));
        } else {
            fragmentRonde1 = ListClickedFragment.newInstance();
        }

    }
});
```

and this

```
public class ListClickedFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

public static final String STRING_TAG = "some_tag_in_here";

public static ListClickedFragment newInstance() {
    return new ListClickedFragment();
}

public static ListClickedFragment newInstance(String pString) {
    ListClickedFragment listClickedFragment = newInstance();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString(STRING_TAG, pString);
}

TextView tvTitle;
TextView tvDesc;
TextView tv;
TextView oop;

public ListClickedFragment() {
}

@Override public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                   Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    final View rootview2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list_clicked, container, false);

    tvTitle = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listClickedTitle);
    if (getArguments() != null && getArguments().getString(STRING_TAG) != null) {
        tvTitle.setText(getArguments().getString(STRING_TAG));
    }
    return rootview2;
}
}
```

Comment: If will definitely try this out when I get home in an hour or 2!  @AndreiVerdes

Answer (score 0):

You can manage all your actions between fragments and activity using Bus realization. This tutorial will help you! [Tutroial...](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaLibrary-EventBusOtto/article.html)

Answer (score 0):

## Step 1

In fragment A, Use a `callback` to get access the activity. You can learn how to use it from here.
[Fragment Callbacks](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#EventCallbacks)

## Step 2

In activity, Use `FragmentManager` to find Fragment B, and then you can get access to the `TextView` in Fragment B