# How do I create an ArrayList of imges from drawable and display it in fragment ListView?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments, arraylist

I have images in fragment that I want to display in a fragment `ListView`.

**This is what I have tried, can u guess what's wrong with my code?**

I made an Integer `ArrayList` of drawable images

```
 ArrayList<Integer> ex1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ex1.add(R.drawable.a);
    ex1.add(R.drawable.b);
    ex1.add(R.drawable.c);
    ex1.add(R.drawable.d);
```

and tried to pass it to fragment like we would pass any `String ArrayList`

I declared in in main activity like this

```
public static final String Data = "list";
```

and then

```
    bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putIntegerArrayList(DATA, ex1);
    Fragment fragment = new ExFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(arguments);
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
    ft.addToBackStack("");
    ft.commit();
```

and then in fragment class

```
private ArrayList<Integer> images = new ArrayList<>();
```

in oncreate of fragment

```
 if (getArguments() != null) {
        images = getArguments().getIntegerArrayList(MainMenu.DATA);
    }
```

and in oncreateview

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ex, container, false);
    ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview);
    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, R.id.text1, images);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

but it gave me `NullPointerException`

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
         at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:395)
         at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
         at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2724)
         at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1811)
         at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:697)
         at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:763)
         at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1641)
         at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2549)
         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15762)
         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4867)
```

**This code works perfect with `Strign ArrayList` if I change from `Integer` to String and put a `String ArrayList`**

Comment: try using `android.R.id.text1` as the third argument in the ArrayAdapter constructor

Comment: @daentech it works fine for string arrays as it is though

Comment: I think you forgot to call `fragment.setArguments(bundle);`.

Comment: @Rami i did called it actually, it missed it copy pasting here, am so sorry  lemme update the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Java Class CustomAdapter

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    String [] Text;
    int [] Image;
    Context context;

    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public CustomAdapter(MainActivity mainActivity, String[] TextItem, int[] mainImages) {
        Text = TextItem;
        context = mainActivity;
        Image = mainImages;
        inflater = ( LayoutInflater )context.
                getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }


    @Override
    // Get number of items in list
    public int getCount() {
        return Text.length;
    }

    @Override
    // Get position of item in list
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    // ???
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public class Holder
    {
        TextView tv;
        ImageView img;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
        Holder holder=new Holder();
        View rowView;

        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.YOURCUSTOMXML, null);

        /** Get relevant view
         * Set image/text resource, based on list name, based on list position
         */
        holder.img=(ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.IMAGEIDINCUSTOMXML);
        holder.img.setImageResource(Image[position]);

        holder.tv=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.TEXTIDINCUSTOMXML);
        holder.tv.setText(Text[position]);

        return rowView;
    }

}
```

This class lets you create your own ListAdapter with a custom XML layout.
You can call it in your fragment instead of `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` when you load the adapter into your `ListView`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort but what should my custom xml contain if i just want to show couple of images one after another?

Comment: @Anders The list adapter takes the single XML file and re-uses it for each item. So whatever you want a single item to look like. Mine was just an `ImageView` and a `TextView` inside the `RelativeLayout` (Which I change from linear). And I set the background to a different colour than the one of my Activity.

Also: If you want to handle clicks based on the position of the item, I think you'll end up having to use this method.

Comment: so I can define an an `ImageView` in xml and put it in `IMAGEIDINCUSTOMXML`? Thank you so much :) i will work on it in abit and will come back at u, i really appreciate ur effort :) and my way of creating Arraylist of drawable and passing it to fragment is correct?

Comment: I don't really know about fragments, as I've never had to use them yet. But if you can load your original list into the fragment, you should be able to do the same since this is just a customized version of the same thing.

But yes. And three things:
1. if you're not using any text at all, you're going to need to take out the text stuff from the adapter, or you're going to get another exception. 2. You can name your XML whatever you like, just make sure you replace `YOURCUSTOMXML` with the XML name. And make sure whatever your `ImageView` id is you replace `IMAGEIDINCUSTOMXML` with that.

Comment: and 3: 'int[] mainImages' is called from the activity that your `listview` displays in. You'll probably have to change the name of `mainimages` in the adapter to whatever you `array` is in your activity. (ex1 looking at your code again.)