# Passing parameters to Fragment at creation time

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm new to Android programming and I'm studying some components and architecture.

I'm now testing Fragments.

I need to pass a List of custom objects from my `Activity` to a nested `Fragment`.

I read this question: [How to pass a variable from Activity to Fragment, and pass it back?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17436298/how-to-pass-a-variable-from-activity-to-fragment-and-pass-it-back) and I noticed that the `Bundle` collection is the best practice to pass parameters during fragment creation.

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
String myMessage = "Stackoverflow is cool!";
bundle.putString("message", myMessage );
FragmentClass fragInfo = new FragmentClass();
fragInfo.setArguments(bundle);
```

But I'm wondering why can't I simply pass my parameters via constructor, say:

```
List<CustomObject> myParameter = new ArrayList<CustomObject>();
MyFragment fragInfo = new MyFragment(myParameter); // custom Fragment constructor
```

Is this a wrong approach? Is the empty constructor used by the framework to instantiate the fragment via reflection or something similar?

Comment: You are right. And they can't make any assumption on the number and type of the arguments of your constructor

Answer (score 2):

At the time when Android wants to recreate the fragment (i.e. app comes from background to foreground), it will use the default no-argument constructor (without parameters). So you should not overload the constructor.