# Android make parcelable object from library

Tags: android, parcel

I want to pass an object from a library as a parameter to a Fragment. How can I make it parcelable to put it into a bundle? I tried creating a new class that extended the object and implemented parcelable, but it didn't work.

The library is [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) and the object I'm trying to pass is the [BarChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartLib/src/main/java/com/github/mikephil/charting/charts/Chart.java).

Comment: If this library is open source or has publicly-visible documentation, you might want to point out the specific class, as you are more likely to get more specific help that way.

Comment: Why can't you pass just the data? A whole bar chart shouldn't be parceled

Comment: @cricket_007 As long as I know, the only way to pass a parameter to a fragment is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17436298/how-to-pass-a-variable-from-activity-to-fragment-and-pass-it-back) which requires parceling the object if it's not of a primitive type, but I may be wrong.

Comment: Please share your code. All I asked is why can't you parcel the actual data, not the entire bar chart?