# Null object reference while trying to pass array list using interface

Tags: android, interface

Hello so I am trying to pass an array list from my activity to the fragment and this is what I did :

FirstActivity :

```
AdminInterface instanceForInterface;

OnCreate
//
System.out.println(results.size) ; //works fine
instanceForInterface.onDataRecieved(results);  // here I am getting the exception
//

public interface AdminInterface {
    void onDataRecieved(ArrayList <Result> response);
}



public void setInterface(UserFragment anInterface) {
    this.instanceForInterface = anInterface;
}
```

Fragment

```
 OnActivityCreated
((FirstActivity) getActivity()).setInterface(this);

 @Override
public void onDataRecieved(ArrayList<Result> response) {
    processData(response);
}
```

Exception

```
Attempt to invoke interface method 'void **************.onDataRecieved(java.util.ArrayList)' on a null object reference
```

What I think :

I am calling this line

`instanceForInterface.onDataRecieved(results);` in  `OnCreate()`

before the initialisation of

`((FirstActivity) getActivity()).setInterface(this);` in `OnActivityCreated()`

Solution Please ??

Thank You

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: put in `onAttach` instead of `OnActivityCreated`

Comment: better to pass `ArrayList` as `Bundle` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17436298/how-to-pass-a-variable-from-activity-to-fragment-and-pass-it-back

Comment: `instanceForInterface` is null for you. You should use debug to check why it is.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your fragment's `onActivityCreated()` method is invoked after your activity's `onCreate()` method.

The smallest change you can make to achieve the behavior you want is to use the `onResumeFragments()` method in your activity. That is, delete the line `instanceForInterface.onDataRecieved(results);` from your `onCreate` and add this code:

```
@Override
protected void onResumeFragments() {
    super.onResumeFragments();
    instanceForInterface.onDataRecieved(results);
}
```

`onResumeFragments()` will be invoked by the system after both your activity's `onCreate()` and your fragment's `onActivityCreated()` methods.

That being said, chances are quite good that you would be better off with a different approach entirely. For instance, you could have your activity expose a getter for `results` and have your fragment retrieve the results to work with (rather than have your activity store a reference to your fragment).

Further reading about the Activity and Fragment lifecycles:
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html