# How can I pass a var of ClipboardManager to Fragment in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have read the artical [How to pass and get value from fragment and activity android kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46551228/how-to-pass-and-get-value-from-fragment-and-activity-android-kotlin)

I have to pass a  var mClipboardManager (see Code A) in a  activity to Fragment.

How can I pass the var ? and how get the var in Fragment?

**Code A**

```
   private lateinit var mClipboardManager: ClipboardManager 

    private val aPrimaryClipChangedListener = ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener {
        if (mClipboardManager.hasPrimaryClip() && mClipboardManager.primaryClipDescription.hasMimeType(ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN) ) {
            var pasteData: String = ""
            val item = mClipboardManager.primaryClip.getItemAt(0)
            pasteData = item.text.toString().trim()
            addClipboardRecord(pasteData)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you really need to pass it? Can't you just `getSystemService()` in the `Fragment`? It's the same system service everywhere.

Comment: You really don't. `Fragment` has access to a `Context` as soon as it's attached, and that's all you need to get a system service. Why can't you get the `ClipboardManager` in the `Fragment`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to pass, you can get this in your fragment, but anw, you can pass `mClipboardManager` from your activity into you fragment by 2 way

***1***. Set value from your activity.

First, get fragment instance using `getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("YourFragmentTag")`

in your fragment, create a method

```
public void setClipboardManager(ClipboardManager clipboardManager) {
  // here you get an instance of clipboardManager, do anything you want
}
```

and call this method in your activity:

```
fragment.setClipboardManager(mClipboardManager)
```

***2***. Get the value of `mClipboardManager` from you fragment

First, create a method in your activity

```
public ClipboardManager getClipboardManager() {
   return mClipboardManager;
}
```

then, in

```
@Override public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (getActivity() instanceof YourActivity) {
            ((YourAcitivity) getActivity()).getClipboardManager()
            // here you get an instance of clipboardManger, do anything you want
        }
    }
```