# How to pass value from global variable application into fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

How to pass value from global variable application into fragment? I got null value error message.

> Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application

Global Variable

```
public class Gl extends Application {

    private String token = "bla bla";

    public void setToken(String token){
        this.token = token;
    }

    public String getToken() {
        return token;
    }
}
```

Fragment

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    private String token;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        token = ((Gl) getActivity().getApplicationContext()).getToken();
    }

  /* .... */

}
```

Comment: When you debug does the Activity launch? Does Activity attach fragment using fragmentManager?

Answer (score 0):

Check your `AndroidManifest.xml` file for definition of your `Gl` class

```
<application
    android:name=".Gl"
```

everything else looks good ...

Comment: your MyFragment onCreate() not inflating/returning any view, please check

Answer (score 0):

I think there is something wrong by default whit your intent. You should use different approach like to put the variable in res/string file and get it by

```
getString(R.string.you_string_id)
```

But if you want to pass some arguments to the fragment you ca do that as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17436298/how-to-pass-a-variable-from-activity-to-fragment-and-pass-it-back)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you must add `G1` class to `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<application android:name=".G1"
...
/>
```

And I advise you to use Dagger2 , for pass value into fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Specify token of G1 class as public static

Comment: Can you provide some more context?