# java.util.Date value changes after takes from constructor in android

Tags: java, android, datetime, datepicker

I passing java.util.Date value to a fragment through arguments

From constructor of the fragment i get the correct value which i passed from previous class

but in onCreateView the java.util.Date value becomes current value

here is my code

```
Date mydate;
 public GraphDashboardDatedFragment(Date selectedDate) {

    this.mydate=selectedDate;
    Log.v("DateBeforePassing",selectedDate.toString());

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_date_dashboard_graph, container, false);
    Log.v("DateAfterPassing",mydate.toString());


    return view;
}
```

and here is my log file

```
10-12 01:06:15.220 24456-24456/? V/DateBeforePassing: Sat Oct 13 10:45:00 GMT+05:30 2018
10-12 01:06:15.240 24456-24456/? V/DateAfterPassing: Fri Oct 12 01:06:05 GMT+05:30 2018
```

DateAfterPassing shows always the current system time

Comment: you must not create a secondary constructor for your fragment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't create constructor with parameters for fragment. Instead, use `setArguments()` after creating fragment instance.
Even better solution is to use static method like `newInstance()`.
Both ways are described in top answers in this question: [How to pass a variable from Activity to Fragment, and pass it back?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17436298/how-to-pass-a-variable-from-activity-to-fragment-and-pass-it-back)